# Working with Inequalities/CDF and Tips

Tags: probability, probability-theory, derivatives, inequality, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have attached an image of a problem I'm working through. [image]

I do get that the cube root of X^3 and cube root of y leaves as with the second line of the solution for the CDF.

But
A. I'm not sure where the 1/2 comes from? 
B. I think it would make sense that the 1/2 be the height to integrate to 1..but it doesn't add up to 1??

Comment: the pdf of a uniform distribution in $[0,2]$ is $f(x)=1/2$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how the 1/2*y^1/2 equals 1?

Comment: The former is a function. More precisely it is a cdf. The cdf evaluated at x is the integral of the pdf up to x. So you don't need to integrate anything, the cdf will be equal to 1 for y=2 (and values larger than 2)

Comment: Ah. why for y=2 and larger?

Comment: sorry, not for y=2 and larger but y=2^3 and larger. The uniform distribution is defined on [0,2], so Y = X^3 is distributed (not uniformly though) on [0,8]. So the cdf is, by construction equal to 1 for y = 8. For values larger than 8 note that the pdf is equal to 0

Comment: Ah perfect. That makes sense. I forgot I was working on the CDF and that is just the accumulated probabilities lol